# GNUPLOT: Lighing effect in 3d trajectory

Tags: gnuplot

I want to use the reflection effect in one of my 3d plots. I know with pm3d I can use the `set pm3d lighting specular 0.6` to implement the lighting effect. All I want is a way to implement the lighting effect for a trajectory plot, like the one attached below.
I am willing to use pm3d for trajectory plot if there is any way, other please specify the way to enable the lighting effect for normal 3d plots.
Thanks
[This is a 3d trajectory plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/la3b3.gif)

The code to generate the attached visualization is:

```
set terminal gif transparent animate delay 05 nooptimize size 1000,1000 font "Arial,10"
set output 'output-tethering.gif'
#set cbrange [0:]
set cbtics textcolor rgb "white"
n=060
k_start=610
k_stop=610
l=600
kappa=0.5
t_wri=50
pi=3.14159265359
load '../gnuplot-palettes-master/viridis.pal'
#set palette rgb 33,13,10  # rainbow
#set palette negative

do for [k=k_start:k_stop]{  
  do for [i=1:n]{
    #set view  i*360/n,i*360/n
    #set view  90,i*360/n
    polar=60
    azi=60+floor(180*sin(i*pi/n)**4)
    set view  polar,azi

    ### do the multiplot plotting section
    set multiplot
    #       set palette rgb 34,35,36  # black red yello white
    set title sprintf("Xist Tethering\n polar=%d; azim=%d \n Time = %d time units (units arbitrary) and kappa = %4.2f",polar,azi,(k-l)*t_wri,kappa) font "Arial,14" textcolor rgb "white"
    unset ztics
    unset ytics
    unset xtics
    unset border
    sp sprintf("fort.%d",k) u 1:2:3:4 w l lw 3.0 palette notitle#pt 7 ps 1.2
    unset multiplot}
  }
```

Here I have a fort.610 file that contains x,y,and z coordinates of the trajectory and a fourth column to assign color palette.

Answer (score 0):

Specular highlighting is calculated only for surfaces (i.e. the individual polygonal facets making up the surface), not for lines.  In a full ray-tracing program you could replace simple 3D lines with a continuously deformed cylinder to make a tube so that it actually has a surface, but gnuplot cannot do that.